# Bundle methods to pass in a constructor

Tags: c#, .net

I have to pass methods from a user control to a WPF. For that, I use delegates (the UserControl call the WPF, so I can't call UserControl from WPF).

in UserControl:

```
myWPF = new WPF1.UserControl1(Method1, Method2, Method3, Method4);
```

in WPF:

```
public delegate int Del1(int i)
public Del1 MyMethod1;
public delegate string Del2(int i)
public Del2 MyMethod2;
public delegate void Del3()
public Del3 MyMethod3;
public delegate void Del4()
public Del4 MyMethod4;

// Constructor
public UserControl1(Del1 MyMethod1, Del2 MyMethod2,Del3 MyMethod3,Del4 MyMethod4)
{
   MyMethod1 = Method1;
   MyMethod2 = Method2;
   MyMethod3 = Method3;
   MyMethod4 = Method4;
}
```

I have many methods to pass. Is it possible to pass un bundle of methods where I have all my methods instead of passing one by one ?

Comment: Use some kind of list. List<Func<object>>..... but better redesign your app.

Comment: @klm_ +1 for "better redesign your app"... seriously, passing functions to a constructor is usually *ugh*, but passing so many that you need to wrap them in a collection is very very ugly. What's the actual problem here? Why do you need to pass methods to the UserControl? Are you not using Commands and MVVM?

Comment: Just pass an interface...  Implemented by an Options class, or a ConstructorHelper

Comment: Bundle some methods together? A bit like an object with methods?

Comment: A  `List<Func<object>>` won't deal with `void` delegates and isn't very flexible about the parameters.

Comment: @Thomas Flinkow : I have separated the WPF, the UserControl and the Model. So when user interacts I have to pass functions to modify the model

Comment: This is definitely one of the primary uses of an `interface`.

Comment: Basically you are doing it wrong and this is an X/Y question  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem , i'm not sure even where to start with this. However why are you creating your usercontrol?  you should be just using it in the xmal on your main page, if you need to add extra functionality, you should really be plumbing it out with dependency properties, and binding to it from the view modals accessible from the the calling page. i think you really want to take a look at the MVVM pattern and user controls a bit more and rethink your design

Comment: @TheGeneral Ok I will read how to implement MVVM more. But why does UserControl can't be used as the View Model part ?

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't the answer to your exact question, I *do* think it's the right answer:

Have a look at [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

To put it simple, this way you define the methods you need in an interface, implement them in a separate class and pass in the interface. You register which class implements the interface at startup of the application (or maybe even dynamically based on context). This way the definition (contract) is separated from the implementation, which gives more flexibility and test-ability.

For more information, have a look at Martin Fowler's explanation of [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)